# SQL Oracle - Optimizing SQL View

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, subquery

I have this gigantic view that I built to return rows containing information on all objects present in the DB (in this case, electronic components). Sadly, the DB is based on `entity-attribute-value` concept, and it being my first experience in a design like this, I've had a hard time creating this view.

There are about `70 000` `entities` (`objects`), described in a total of over `900 000` rows... Thus, I understand that most of the cost is located in the subquery where I select the `entities` based on a `"Part Classification"`, but it is a requirement. So here is the query:

```
SELECT  PART_NUMBER
        ,PART_NAME
        ,PART_STATE
        ,LAST_REVISION
        ,LAST_ITERATION
        ,CREATED_BY
        ,MODIFIED_BY
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Internal Comments',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Description"
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'RoHS Compliant' AND ATTRIBUTE_VALUE <> 'Unknown' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ELSE null END) AS "RoHs"
        ,(MIN(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) ||
            (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) > 1
                  THEN ' K - ' || MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE || ' K' END)
             END)
            ) AS "Operating_Temp"
        ,<Others columns with the same logic (about 18 more)>
FROM    (
        SELECT  A1.*
                ,U.FULLNAME AS CREATED_BY
                ,U2.FULLNAME AS MODIFIED_BY
        FROM    (
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2 AS PART_ID
                    ,P.IDA2A2 AS PARTVERSION_ID
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER AS PART_NUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME AS PART_NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE AS PART_STATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO AS LAST_REVISION
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS LAST_ITERATION
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO AS IS_LATEST
                    ,SD.DISPLAYNAME AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME
                    ,CAST(SV.VALUE2 AS VARCHAR2(1500)) AS ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
                    ,SV.IDA2A2
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGVALUE SV
                ON  SV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGDEFINITION SD
                ON  SV.IDA3A6 = SD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2
                    ,P.IDA2A2
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO
                    ,UD.DISPLAYNAME
                    ,CAST(UV.VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1500))
                    ,UV.IDA2A2
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.UNITVALUE UV
                ON  UV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.UNITDEFINITION UD
                ON  UV.IDA3A6 = UD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
            UNION ALL
            <3 more tables following the same logic (for floats, integer and bools)>
        ) A1
            JOIN    WC.WTPART P2
                ON  A1.PARTVERSION_ID = P2.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM1
                ON  A1.PART_ID = PM1.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTUSER U
                ON  P2.IDA3D2ITERATIONINFO = U.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTUSER U2
                ON  P2.IDA3B2ITERATIONINFO = U2.IDA2A2
        WHERE       A1.LAST_REVISION =    
                                (
                                    SELECT  MAX(VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO)
                                    FROM    WC.WTPART P3
                                    JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM3
                                        ON  P3.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM3.IDA2A2
                                    WHERE   PM3.IDA2A2 = A1.PART_ID
                                )
            AND EXISTS      (   
                            SELECT  1
                            FROM
                            (
                                SELECT  PM.IDA2A2 AS PART_ID
                                        ,P.IDA2A2 AS PARTVERSION_ID
                                        ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER AS PART_NUMBER
                                        ,PM.NAME AS PART_NAME
                                        ,P.STATESTATE AS PART_STATE
                                        ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO AS LAST_REVISION
                                        ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS LAST_ITERATION
                                        ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO AS IS_LATEST
                                        ,SD.DISPLAYNAME AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME
                                        ,CAST(SV.VALUE2 AS VARCHAR2(1500)) AS ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
                                FROM    WC.WTPART P
                                JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                                    ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
                                JOIN    WC.STRINGVALUE SV
                                    ON  SV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
                                JOIN    WC.STRINGDEFINITION SD
                                    ON  SV.IDA3A6 = SD.IDA2A2
                                WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                            ) A2
                            WHERE   A2.PARTVERSION_ID = A1.PARTVERSION_ID
                                AND A2.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Part Classification'
                                AND A2.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE IN 
                                (
                                    'class040040', 'class040036', 'class040038', 
                                    'class040041', 'class040042', 'class040043'
                                    <more classvalues, variates between 4 and 100 (at 100 it takes 52 secs)>
                                )
                            )
    )
GROUP BY PART_NUMBER
         ,PART_NAME
         ,PART_STATE
         ,LAST_REVISION
         ,LAST_ITERATION
         ,CREATED_BY
         ,MODIFIED_BY
;
```

Here are some information on the tables used:

- `WTPART` gives the `version`, `iteration` and `state` of each `entity`.
- `WTPARTMASTER` gives the `part_number` and `part_name` of each `entity`
- `WTUSER` gives the ``created_by`and`modified_by`users for each`entity`
- `<datatype>DEFINITION` gives the name of the attribute (where `<datatype>` is equal to `string`, `float`, `boolean`, etc.)
- `<datatype>VALUE` gives the value for a said attributing for each `entity` (thus, each `entity` has between 15-20 attributes with values)

In `Table A1`, we select each `attribute` and `value` for each `entity` of all possible datatypes (`string`, `floats`, etc.) and find which users modified. Based on `LATESTITERATIONINFO` field, we get latest iteration, therefore, to get latest version of said `entity`, we add the `WHERE` clause selecting `MAX(VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO)` (Entity are versioned following `Version.Iteration` (ex. `C.25`)).

In `Table A2`, we select 1 where `entities` match our classification researched for the `Attribute_Name` = `"Part Classification"` and match by ID with `Table A1`. Then, if row exists, it means that we can output information about that `Part_Number`.

Finally, we `GROUP BY` to use aggregate functions in the attributes filtered.

I've tried looking at the EXPLAIN PLAN to see what can be done, but I have no idea how to simplify `Table A2` subquery. Also, I'm positive it is that part of the query which is slow since I completely removed it (thus losing notion of classification of my `entities`) and it runs in 7 secs, but for all 70k parts. For comparison purposes, it takes 12 secs for 40 parts when I add `Table A2` subquery.

Any tips on how I can reduce the execution time (I can add additional information if needed)?

***EDIT #1***

<s>I put a `WHERE` clause right before the `GROUP BY` and it speed up a bit, but not enough</s> -- It gave me wrong data

***EDIT #1.1***

I split my view in 2 views: One that gathers all IDs with a list of `Part Classification`. That query takes less than 0.5s. Then, having both IDs, I do the match with by IDs, since they are indexed, thus it should be faster. And it is, but only by a couple of seconds.

I know realize that the computing times comes from the `GROUP BY` clause. Furthermore, removing the columns containing MAX function from the view speed the execution by an important amount.

***EDIT #2***

Here is the `Explain Plan`

```
Plan hash value: 1854531935

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                         |     1 |  1595 |       | 35623   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY                               |                         |     1 |  1595 |       | 35623   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|*  2 |   FILTER                                     |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                              |                         |    10 | 15950 |       | 35612   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                             |                         |    10 | 15950 |       | 35612   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                            |                         |    10 | 15720 |       | 35611   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                           |                         |    10 | 15490 |       | 35610   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                          |                         |    10 | 15300 |       | 35609   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|*  8 |         HASH JOIN                            |                         |    10 | 15230 |       | 35608   (1)| 00:07:08 |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                        |                         |     2 |   148 |       |   130   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                       |                         |     2 |   134 |       |   129   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                      |                         |     2 |   100 |       |   128   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|* 12 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL                | STRINGDEFINITION        |     1 |    28 |       |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | STRINGVALUE             |     2 |    44 |       |   118   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|* 14 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                | STRINGVALUE$COMPOSITE2  |  5780 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | WTPART                  |     1 |    17 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_WTPART               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PK_WTPARTMASTER         |     1 |     7 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |          VIEW                                |                         |  1062K|  1467M|       | 35476   (1)| 00:07:06 |
|  19 |           UNION-ALL                          |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 20 |            HASH JOIN                         |                         |   898K|   110M|       | 27326   (1)| 00:05:28 |
|  21 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL                | STRINGDEFINITION        |   677 | 18956 |       |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |             HASH JOIN                        |                         |   898K|    86M|  7312K| 27314   (1)| 00:05:28 |
|* 23 |              HASH JOIN                       |                         | 82231 |  6343K|  3616K|  3490   (1)| 00:00:42 |
|  24 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | WTPART                  | 82231 |  2650K|       |  2741   (1)| 00:00:33 |
|* 25 |                INDEX SKIP SCAN               | WTPART$COMPOSITE14      | 82231 |       |       |    52   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |               VIEW                           | index$_join$_004        | 71824 |  3226K|       |   377   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|* 27 |                HASH JOIN                     |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|  28 |                 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE3 | 71824 |  3226K|       |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |                 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE  | 71824 |  3226K|       |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL               | STRINGVALUE             |  3080K|    64M|       | 18503   (1)| 00:03:43 |
|* 31 |            HASH JOIN                         |                         | 80219 |  9714K|       |  4021   (1)| 00:00:49 |
|  32 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL                | UNITDEFINITION          |   365 |  9490 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |             HASH JOIN                        |                         |   100K|  9612K|  4072K|  4016   (1)| 00:00:49 |
|  34 |              VIEW                            | index$_join$_011        | 71824 |  3226K|       |   377   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|* 35 |               HASH JOIN                      |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|  36 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE3 | 71824 |  3226K|       |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE  | 71824 |  3226K|       |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |              HASH JOIN                       |                         |   100K|  5100K|  3048K|  3137   (1)| 00:00:38 |
|  39 |               INDEX FULL SCAN                | UNITVALUE$COMPOSITE0    |   100K|  1863K|       |    72   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | WTPART                  | 82231 |  2650K|       |  2741   (1)| 00:00:33 |
|* 41 |                INDEX SKIP SCAN               | WTPART$COMPOSITE14      | 82231 |       |       |    52   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |            HASH JOIN                         |                         | 82231 |  9716K|       |  3973   (1)| 00:00:48 |
|  43 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL                | BOOLEANDEFINITION       |    31 |   775 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |             HASH JOIN                        |                         | 82231 |  7709K|  4072K|  3969   (1)| 00:00:48 |
|  45 |              VIEW                            | index$_join$_032        | 71824 |  3226K|       |   377   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|* 46 |               HASH JOIN                      |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|  47 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE3 | 71824 |  3226K|       |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  48 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | WTPARTMASTER$COMPOSITE  | 71824 |  3226K|       |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 49 |              HASH JOIN                       |                         | 82231 |  4015K|  3616K|  3153   (1)| 00:00:38 |
|  50 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | WTPART                  | 82231 |  2650K|       |  2741   (1)| 00:00:33 |
|* 51 |                INDEX SKIP SCAN               | WTPART$COMPOSITE14      | 82231 |       |       |    52   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |               INDEX FULL SCAN                | BOOLEANVALUE$COMPOSITE0 |   139K|  2315K|       |    44   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  53 |            NESTED LOOPS                      |                         |   749 |  1078K|       |   155   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  54 |             NESTED LOOPS                     |                         |   749 |  1078K|       |   155   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  55 |              VIEW                            | VW_JF_SET$368F68B3      |   749 |  1045K|       |    81   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  56 |               UNION-ALL                      |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
|  57 |                NESTED LOOPS                  |                         |   745 | 55130 |       |    78   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |                 NESTED LOOPS                 |                         |   745 | 55130 |       |    78   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |                  MERGE JOIN                  |                         |   745 | 30545 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| FLOATDEFINITION         |    41 |   984 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  61 |                    INDEX FULL SCAN           | PK_FLOATDEFINITION      |    41 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 62 |                   SORT JOIN                  |                         |   756 | 12852 |       |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |                    INDEX FULL SCAN           | FLOATVALUE$COMPOSITE0   |   756 | 12852 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 64 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_WTPART               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 65 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | WTPART                  |     1 |    33 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  66 |                NESTED LOOPS                  |                         |     4 |   328 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  67 |                 NESTED LOOPS                 |                         |     4 |   328 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  68 |                  NESTED LOOPS                |                         |     4 |   196 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  69 |                   INDEX FULL SCAN            | INTEGERVALUE$COMPOSITE0 |     4 |    68 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  70 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| INTEGERDEFINITION       |     1 |    32 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 71 |                    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_INTEGERDEFINITION    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 72 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_WTPART               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 73 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | WTPART                  |     1 |    33 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 74 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PK_WTPARTMASTER         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  75 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | WTPARTMASTER            |     1 |    46 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 76 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_WTPARTMASTER         |     1 |     7 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  77 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | WTPART                  |     1 |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 78 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_WTPART               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  79 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | WTUSER                  |     1 |    23 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 80 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | PK_WTUSER               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 81 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_WTUSER               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  82 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | WTUSER                  |     1 |    23 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  83 |    SORT AGGREGATE                            |                         |     1 |    17 |       |            |          |
|  84 |     NESTED LOOPS                             |                         |     4 |    68 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 85 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_WTPARTMASTER         |     1 |     7 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  86 |      FIRST ROW                               |                         |     4 |    40 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 87 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)             | WTPART$UNIQUE50         |     4 |    40 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A1"."LAST_REVISION"= (SELECT MAX("P3"."VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO") FROM "WC"."WTPARTMASTER" 
          "PM3","WC"."WTPART" "P3" WHERE "P3"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"=:B1 AND "PM3"."IDA2A2"=:B2))
   8 - access("P"."IDA2A2"="A1"."PARTVERSION_ID")
  12 - filter("SD"."DISPLAYNAME"='Part Classification')
  13 - filter(CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040356' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040354' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040357' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040358' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040359' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040361' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040355' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040367' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040363' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040365' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040366' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040360' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040362' OR CAST("SV"."VALUE2" AS 
          VARCHAR2(1500))='ABBclass040364')
  14 - access("SV"."IDA3A6"="SD"."IDA2A2")
  15 - filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  16 - access("SV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  17 - access("P"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"="PM"."IDA2A2")
  20 - access("SV"."IDA3A6"="SD"."IDA2A2")
  22 - access("SV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  23 - access("P"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"="PM"."IDA2A2")
  25 - access("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
   filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  27 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  31 - access("UV"."IDA3A6"="UD"."IDA2A2")
  33 - access("P"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"="PM"."IDA2A2")
  35 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  38 - access("UV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  41 - access("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
   filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  42 - access("BV"."IDA3A6"="BD"."IDA2A2")
  44 - access("P"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"="PM"."IDA2A2")
  46 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  49 - access("BV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  51 - access("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
   filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  62 - access("FV"."IDA3A6"="FD"."IDA2A2")
   filter("FV"."IDA3A6"="FD"."IDA2A2")
  64 - access("FV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  65 - filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  71 - access("IV"."IDA3A6"="ID"."IDA2A2")
  72 - access("IV"."IDA3A4"="P"."IDA2A2")
  73 - filter("P"."LATESTITERATIONINFO"=1)
  74 - access("ITEM_1"="PM"."IDA2A2")
  76 - access("A1"."PART_ID"="PM1"."IDA2A2")
  78 - access("A1"."PARTVERSION_ID"="P2"."IDA2A2")
  80 - access("P2"."IDA3D2ITERATIONINFO"="U"."IDA2A2")
  81 - access("P2"."IDA3B2ITERATIONINFO"="U2"."IDA2A2")
  85 - access("PM3"."IDA2A2"=:B1)
  87 - access("P3"."IDA3MASTERREFERENCE"=:B1)
```

Comment: .  Please run an EXPLAN PLAN and post the results.

Comment: Here it is ! I omitted the ``Predicate Information (identified by operation id):``. If you need it too I can post it!

Comment: This explain plan is incomplete, missing `predicate information` table.

Comment: Just added the missing table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I successfully reduce my query by a considerable amount.
The subquery having 5 tables with  `UNION ALL` is over a million rows. Therefore, treatment of all those rows was what was taking so long. So I had to find a way to reduce the amount of data retrieved.

In order to reduce it, I added a new view, which returns all IDs associated with a set of `Part Classification`. Then, having that list, I then filter with a `WHERE` clause after each table in the `UNION ALL` query which will only retrieve the data I want to treat, thus reducing by **a lot** the executing time. Here is the line added `AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM XXX_CLASS)`, where XXX equals the classification part !

here is the final query:

```
SELECT  PART_NUMBER
        ,PART_NAME
        ,PART_STATE
        ,LAST_REVISION
        ,LAST_ITERATION
        ,CREATED_BY
        ,MODIFIED_BY
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Internal Comments',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Description"
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'RoHS Compliant' AND ATTRIBUTE_VALUE <> 'Unknown' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ELSE null END) AS "RoHs"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Capacitance',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Value"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Tolerance Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Tolerance"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Power Dissipation',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Power"
        ,(MIN(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Supply Voltage' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) ||
            (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Supply Voltage' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) > 1
                  THEN ' V, ' || MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Supply Voltage' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE || ' V' END)
             END)
            ) AS "Voltage"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Input Current Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Current"
        ,(MIN(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) ||
            (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE END) > 1
                  THEN ' K - ' || MAX(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Operating Temperature' THEN ATTRIBUTE_VALUE || ' K' END)
             END)
            ) AS "Operating_Temp"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 1',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Manufacturer_1"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 1 Part Number',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Mfg_Part_Number_1"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Datasheet 1 Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Datasheet_1"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 2',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Manufacturer_2"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 2 Part Number',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Mfg_Part_Number_2"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Datasheet 2 Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Datasheet_2"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 3',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Manufacturer_3"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Manufacturer 3 Part Number',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Mfg_Part_Number_3"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Datasheet 3 Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Datasheet_3"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Footprint Reference Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Footprint Ref"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Footprint Path Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Footprint Path"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Library Reference Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Library Ref"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Library Path Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Library Path"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Package Altium',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Package"
        ,MAX(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_NAME,'Part Classification',ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)) AS "Classification"
FROM    (
        SELECT  A1.*
                ,U.FULLNAME AS CREATED_BY
                ,U2.FULLNAME AS MODIFIED_BY
        FROM    (
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2 AS PART_ID
                    ,P.IDA2A2 AS PARTVERSION_ID
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER AS PART_NUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME AS PART_NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE AS PART_STATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO AS LAST_REVISION
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS LAST_ITERATION
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO AS IS_LATEST
                    ,SD.DISPLAYNAME AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME
                    ,CAST(SV.VALUE2 AS VARCHAR2(1500)) AS ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGVALUE SV
                ON  SV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGDEFINITION SD
                ON  SV.IDA3A6 = SD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM ABB_ADC_CLASS)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2
                    ,P.IDA2A2
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO
                    ,UD.DISPLAYNAME
                    ,CAST(UV.VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1500))
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.UNITVALUE UV
                ON  UV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.UNITDEFINITION UD
                ON  UV.IDA3A6 = UD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM ABB_ADC_CLASS)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2
                    ,P.IDA2A2
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO
                    ,FD.DISPLAYNAME
                    ,CAST(FV.VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1500))
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.FLOATVALUE FV
                ON  FV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.FLOATDEFINITION FD
                ON  FV.IDA3A6 = FD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM ABB_ADC_CLASS)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2
                    ,P.IDA2A2
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO
                    ,ID.DISPLAYNAME
                    ,CAST(IV.VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1500))
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.INTEGERVALUE IV
                ON  IV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.INTEGERDEFINITION ID
                ON  IV.IDA3A6 = ID.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM ABB_ADC_CLASS)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2
                    ,P.IDA2A2
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO
                    ,BD.DISPLAYNAME
                    ,CAST(BV.VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1500))
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.BOOLEANVALUE BV
                ON  BV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.BOOLEANDEFINITION BD
                ON  BV.IDA3A6 = BD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND P.IDA2A2 IN (SELECT PARTVERSION_ID FROM ABB_ADC_CLASS)
        ) A1
            JOIN    WC.WTPART P2
                ON  A1.PARTVERSION_ID = P2.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM1
                ON  A1.PART_ID = PM1.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTUSER U
                ON  P2.IDA3D2ITERATIONINFO = U.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.WTUSER U2
                ON  P2.IDA3B2ITERATIONINFO = U2.IDA2A2
        )
GROUP BY    PART_NUMBER
            ,PART_NAME
            ,PART_STATE
            ,LAST_REVISION
            ,LAST_ITERATION
            ,CREATED_BY
            ,MODIFIED_BY
```

Here is the view that gives all IDs in a given `Part Classification`:

```
SELECT  PART_ID
        ,PARTVERSION_ID
        ,PART_NUMBER
        ,PART_NAME
FROM    (
        SELECT  A1.*
        FROM    (
            SELECT  PM.IDA2A2 AS PART_ID
                    ,P.IDA2A2 AS PARTVERSION_ID
                    ,PM.WTPARTNUMBER AS PART_NUMBER
                    ,PM.NAME AS PART_NAME
                    ,P.STATESTATE AS PART_STATE
                    ,P.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO AS LAST_REVISION
                    ,P.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS LAST_ITERATION
                    ,P.LATESTITERATIONINFO AS IS_LATEST
                    ,SD.DISPLAYNAME AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME
                    ,CAST(SV.VALUE2 AS VARCHAR2(1500)) AS ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
                    ,SV.IDA2A2
            FROM    WC.WTPART P
            JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM
                ON  P.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGVALUE SV
                ON  SV.IDA3A4 = P.IDA2A2
            JOIN    WC.STRINGDEFINITION SD
                ON  SV.IDA3A6 = SD.IDA2A2
            WHERE   P.LATESTITERATIONINFO = 1
                AND SD.DISPLAYNAME = 'Part Classification'
                AND SV.VALUE2 IN 
                        (
                            'class040040', 'class040036', 'class040038'
                            , 'class040041', 'class040042', 'class040043'
                        )
        ) A1
        WHERE       A1.LAST_REVISION =    
                    (
                        SELECT  MAX(VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO)
                        FROM    WC.WTPART P3
                        JOIN    WC.WTPARTMASTER PM3
                            ON  P3.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE = PM3.IDA2A2
                        WHERE   PM3.IDA2A2 = A1.PART_ID
                    )
    )
GROUP BY PART_ID
        ,PARTVERSION_ID
        ,PART_NUMBER
        ,PART_NAME
```